# Cannot build tauri App for windows using circleCI

Tags: webview, circleci, tauri

I have a fresh tauri 1.3.0 project, using Node 20, rust 1.69.0 and Svelte 3.59 and I am trying to achieve a tripple build [using circle.ci](https://circleci.com/docs/using-windows/):

Linux and MacOS work nice, but Windows has a problem with the webview2 dependency:

### What do I need to fix?

All starting nicely:

```
> tauri-browser@0.0.5 tauri:build
> tauri build

     Running beforeBuildCommand `npm run build`

> tauri-browser@0.0.5 build
> vite build

vite v4.3.8 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 39 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
dist/index.html                  0.48 kB │ gzip:  0.32 kB
dist/assets/index-dd351b52.css   3.02 kB │ gzip:  0.96 kB
dist/assets/index-1538e646.js   41.60 kB │ gzip: 11.71 kB
✓ built in 1.56s
    Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded adler v1.0.2
  ...
```

...more Downloading and Compilation without any warnings or errors, but then...

```
   Compiling raw-window-handle v0.5.0
   Compiling toml v0.7.3
error: failed to run custom build command for `webview2-com-sys v0.19.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\project\src-tauri\target\release\build\webview2-com-sys-bbbb0c2631a4b59f\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=C:\Users\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\project\src-tauri\target\release\build\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\out\x64

  --- stderr
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\arm64\\WebView2Loader.dll" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\arm64\\WebView2Loader.dll"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\arm64\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\arm64\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\arm64\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\arm64\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x64\\WebView2Loader.dll" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x64\\WebView2Loader.dll"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x64\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x64\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x64\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x64\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x86\\WebView2Loader.dll" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x86\\WebView2Loader.dll"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x86\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x86\\WebView2Loader.dll.lib"
  Copy from "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\webview2-com-sys-0.19.0\\x86\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib" -> "C:\\Users\\circleci.PACKER-64370BA5\\project\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\webview2-com-sys-c28652fe6978543c\\out\\x86\\WebView2LoaderStatic.lib"
  
  Error: Io(Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" })
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
       Error failed to build app: failed to build app

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

This is my `.circleci/config.yml`:

( and yes, I got a checksum error, until I ignored it. And I also tried the comment out approach for installing webview)

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.1.0
  win: circleci/windows@5.0
  mac: circleci/macos@1.1.0

jobs:
  build-linux:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/rust:1.69.0-node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y curl wget
            sudo apt-get install -y libglib2.0-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev build-essential
            sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libgtk-3-dev libayatana-appindicator3-dev librsvg2-dev
      - node/install:
          node-version: "20"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run tauri:build
      - run:
          name: Prepare artifacts
          command: |
            mkdir -p ./build/linux
            mv ./src-tauri/target/release/bundle/deb/*.deb ./build/linux
            mv ./src-tauri/target/release/bundle/appimage/*.AppImage ./build/linux
      - store_artifacts:
          path: build

  build-windows:
    executor: win/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Node.js
          command: choco install nodejs -y --no-progress --version=20.0.0
      - run:
          name: Install Rust
          command: choco install rust -y --no-progress
      - run:
          name: Show Rust Version
          command: rustc --version
      - run:
          name: Show Cargo Version
          command: cargo --version
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: choco install gtk-runtime -y --no-progress
      - run:
          name: Install Microsoft WebView2 Runtime
          command: |
            choco install webview2-runtime -y --no-progress --ignore-checksums
      # - run:
      #     name: Install WebView2 Runtime
      #     shell: powershell.exe
      #     command: |
      #       $webview2RTUrl = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=2124703"
      #       $webview2RTFile = "MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe"
      #       Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $webview2RTUrl -OutFile $webview2RTFile
      #       Start-Process -FilePath $webview2RTFile -Args "/silent /install" -NoNewWindow -Wait
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run tauri:build
      - run:
          name: Prepare artifacts
          command: |
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$HOME\\project\\build\\windows"
            Move-Item -Path "C:\\path\\to\\your\\windows\\artifacts\\*" -Destination "$HOME\\project\\build\\windows"
      - store_artifacts:
          path: "$HOME\\project\\build"

  build-macos:
    macos:
      xcode: 14.3.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Node.js
          command: brew install node@20 && echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@20/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
      - run:
          name: Install Rust
          command: curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
      - run:
          name: Source bash profile
          command: source ~/.bash_profile
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run tauri:build
      - run:
          name: Move Binary to Desired Location
          command: |
            mkdir -p ./build/macos
            mv ./src-tauri/target/release/bundle/macos/*.app ./build/macos
            mv ./src-tauri/target/release/bundle/dmg/*.dmg ./build/macos
      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./build

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build-linux
      - build-windows
      - build-macos
```